# How to measure div size including children

Tags: html, css, dom

I have a div which has display: block. Inside of it, I have another div with display: inline-block. When I measure the size of the containing div, children bounds aren't taken into account. It's readily visible in a browser's inspector. Is there a way to stretch the containing div so that its bounds contain bounds on inline block?

Here is code which demonstrates the problem:

```
<div style="display: inline">
  <div style="display: inline">aaa</div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red"></div>
</div>
```

P.S. I can't change inline on the container to the inline block. The only thing I can change is inline-block div's attributes.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply `display: table;` on the container div. Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49eWY/).

Comment: I can't set block here. I use this code for quite a complicated layout (for an editor app), which will be broken if I change inline to block. The only thing, I can change is inline-block's attributes – Konstantin Solomatov just now edit

Answer (score 1):

Set `height` and `width` to `auto`

```
  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color:green;width:auto; height:auto;">
  <div>aaa</div>                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red;opacity:0.5;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't change inline on the container to the inline block. The only thing I can change is inline-block div's attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the contents within a div and give it a value of `display: block;`

DEMO  http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/649EB/

CSS

```
.container {
    background: #ccc;
}
.inner {
    display: block;
    background: #000;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container" style="display: inline">
    <div class="inner">
        <div style="display: inline">aaa</div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDITED

If you can use `display: block;` then I would set it to `height: auto;`

[updated] DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/649EB/1/

Comment: I can't set block here. I use this code for quite a complicated layout (for an editor app), which will be broken if I change inline to block. The only thing, I can change is inline-block's attributes